# Should "law" and "legal" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Here are some similar tags:

- [law](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) × 32
- [legal](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) × 137

Comment: I have performed this merge.

Answer (score 2):

These tags mean essentially the same thing and should be merged.   [legal](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) should be the canonical tag because it is used more often.

Comment: I agree to merge [tag:law] to [tag:legal].